# Typescript and VS2013, live error checking stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, error-checking

For some reason VS is no longer finding errors in some of my TS code file while editing. It was working perfectly until I tried to compile.

Now I see the compiler errors sitting in my Error List window, but no live editing errors (or whatever they are called.)

But this appears to only be the case for .ts files created before I had compiled. Live errors are still showing up on new .ts file I create.

Anyone know how to turn this back on for the older files?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: I have. I have not rebooted Windows yet. When I have a chance I will report back on that.